# Knockout Custom binding doesn't update

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js, tinymce

I have this customized data binding with a TinyMCE Wysiwyg editor, and for some reason it would´t update when I select a new text input. Something tells me that maybe the update should destroy the binding just to re-initialize it, but I cannot get that to work.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tinymce = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().tinymceOptions || {};
    var modelValue = valueAccessor();
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    var el = $(element)

    //handle edits made in the editor. Updates after an undo point is reached.
    options.setup = function (ed) {
      console.log(ed)
      ed.onChange.add(function (ed, l) {
        if (ko.isWriteableObservable(modelValue)) {
          modelValue(l.content);
        }
      });
    };

    //handle destroying an editor 
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
      setTimeout(function () { $(element).tinymce().remove() }, 0)
    });

    //$(element).tinymce(options);
    setTimeout(function () { $(element).tinymce(options); }, 0);
    el.html(value);

  },
  update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {

    var el = $(element)
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    var id = el.attr('id')
    alert("Value=" + value);

    //handle programmatic updates to the observable
    // also makes sure it doesn't update it if it's the same. 
    // otherwise, it will reload the instance, causing the cursor to jump.
    if (id !== undefined) {  // Does not work
      var content = tinyMCE.getInstanceById(id).getContent({ format: 'raw' });
      if (content !== value) {
        //el.html(value);
        el.val(value);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The update section is only called once for the first selection. Selecting a new text batch does not trigger the alert. Why?

Fiddler here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wf7xk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stops working because an exception is thrown in the `tinyMCE.getInstanceById(id)` line of the update function.

Here is the fixed and simplified version:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tinymce = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().tinymceOptions || {};

        function writeModelValue(ed) {
            var modelValue = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(modelValue)) {
                modelValue(ed.getContent());
            }
        }

        //handle edits made in the editor
        options.setup = function (ed) {
            ed.onChange.add(writeModelValue); //on add undo point
            ed.onUndo.add(writeModelValue); //on undo
            ed.onRedo.add(writeModelValue); //on redo
        };

        $(element).tinymce(options);

        //handle destroying an editor 
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).tinymce().remove();
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if(value !== $(element).html()) {
            $(element).html(value);
        }
    }
};
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g23Qx/3/

Comment: Thanx @LostInComputer! So simple. So brilliant! :)

Comment: Seems however that the edit acts a bit strange. When formatting BOLD/Italic/Underline (possible more) and using arrow keys to left/right, the cursor jumps to the start of the text.


Is there something missing in the init part?

Comment: Fixed. Only update the value if it is different from the current

Comment: That fixed the arrow keys, but not the formatting and the linefeed after CRLF…

Comment: Fixed the problem. Turns out that l.content is not equal to ed.getContent()!

Comment: Another thing: I get an error message on this line:

 setTimeout(function () { $(element).tinymce().remove() }, 0)

Error saying: TypeError: $(...).tinymce(...) is undefined

Any idea what might causing this?

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Hw9zj/1/) what you did? Remove the setTimeout because it causes the remove to be executed after initialization. Look at the console log for the sequence of events.